# HIghlights Panel not showing up

Tags: page-layout, console

I have turned on the highlights panel by going to page layout properties and also added fields on the highlights panel, but fields are not showing up on the console. Are there any more settings to do?

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutcustomize_highlights_panel_config.htm&language=en_US

Comment: It would be great if you could be a little more specific. Thanks.

Comment: I have added fields in highlights panel (Go to any pagelayout and you will see it on the top) but these fields won't show up in console view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been investigating this issue for days, and have found the problem at last.

All your configuration is OK, it's just that the highlights panel might be masked.
Open the Service Cloud Console (also works for Sales Cloud Console, I suppose).
Open a primary tab item, for example Account : just under the tab, there is a thin line/bar, separator between tabs and their content below. Hover over that thin line/bar : you will see an arrow pop up on the line, in the middle of the screen (horizontally).
Click on that arrow to toggle the masking/unmasking of the hghlights bar.

At last, highlights panel, I can see you !

Answer (score 2):

Highlights Panel will only show up on the Primary Tabs in Service Cloud and not on the Subtabs. Kind of annoying. Edit you app under the "Choose How Records Display" section. Set "Case" "As a primary tab". Hit Save. Viola

Answer (score 1):

Peter, did you ever receive an answer for this?  I am looking for an answer to the exact same problem.  Everything is enabled and checked properly according to the manuals, but I can't see the highlights panel no matter what screen I look at, including the Console tab.